# Can I pause a Hyper-V guest via the command line?

Tags: hyper-v, command-line-interface

Can I pause a Hyper-V guest via the command line?

If so, could I do this over the network from my Win7 box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/) is a suite of powershell commands to perform actions against Hyper-V (including starting/stopping). They should be usable remotely through PS Remoting as well, but I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible - check out the powershell commands.

http://capilla.codeplex.com/

or

http://www.synergyonline.com/blog/blog-moss/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=21